# MYSQL RAND() will not generate correct listing

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a problem getting the right results out of my select. Table wp_rdp_category_images has 3 columns: id (unique) - category_name - category_image.

In the select below I need as result max 4 x category_name and from each category_name, 1 category_image.

Can someone help me correct this select? Would be very nice. Thanks in advance.

Here the php code:

```
function show_game_category_images_func() {
    $content = '';
    $i = 1;
    $record = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results('
    SELECT * FROM wp_rdp_category_images
    ORDER BY `category_name`, RAND()
    LIMIT 4 
    ');

    if($record){
        foreach($record as $key => $rec){                   
            // if($key == 'picture' && $rec != null && $rec != '')     
            $rec = '<img src="'.$upload_url.$record->category_image.'" width="150" height="150">';

            if ($i == 1) {
                echo '<span><img src="'.$upload_url.$rec->category_image.'" ></span>';  // even
            }
            if ($i == 2) {
                echo '<span><img src="'.$upload_url.$rec->category_image.'" ></span><br>';  // even
            }
            else {
                echo '<span><img src="'.$upload_url.$rec->category_image.'" ></span>';   // odd
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }   
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('show_game_category_images', 'show_game_category_images_func');
```

My SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_rdp_category_images`    
ORDER BY `category_name`, RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Here is a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_rdp_category_images` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `category_image` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;

INSERT INTO `wp_rdp_category_images` (`id`, `category_name`, `category_image`) VALUES
(1, 'natuur', 'natuur1.jpg'),
(2, 'natuur', 'natuur4.jpg'),
(4, 'aarde', 'aarde3.jpg'),
(5, 'sport', 'sport2.jpg'),
(6, 'aarde', 'aarde3.jpg'),
(7, 'auto', 'autogrijs.jpg'),
(8, 'auto', 'autowit.jpg'),
(9, 'auto', 'autoblack.jpg'),
(10, 'auto', 'autoroodzwart.jpg'),
(11, 'aarde', 'aarde1.jpg'),
(12, 'aarde', 'aarde2.jpg'),
(13, 'sport', 'sport4.jpg'),
(14, 'sport', 'sport3.jpg'),
(15, 'sport', 'sport1.jpg'),
(16, 'natuur', 'natuur2.jpg'),
(17, 'natuur', 'natuur3.jpg'),
(18, 'people', 'people1.jpg'),
(19, 'people', 'people2.jpg'),
(20, 'people', 'people3.jpg'),
(21, 'people', 'people4.jpg');
```

Comment: And what do you want? For it to pick the correct random row ! Do you have some error you want to share with us? Some Expect Results you can show?

Comment: I get nor errors. Only need 4 unique category_names including related images. LIke this result: natuur', 'natuur1.jpg
aarde', 'aarde3.jpg
auto', 'autowit.jpg
people', 'people2.jpg

Comment: Oh then this just turned into an interesting question. Here's my upvote (for the interesting part of it). Note, however, that not all your data is unique (excluding the auto_inc)

Comment: That is correct. Exclude the id field the rest is NOT unique. I have a lot of category_names with images. But I need max 4 to get from my select. 4 unique names from the table. I did not ment an unique field.

Comment: To clarify: It sounds like you want a resultset containing four randomly chosen categories. Associated with each category you want one image chosen at random from among the images for that category. Is that correct? Please [edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
select     category_name,
           (select   category_image
            from     wp_rdp_category_images
            where    category_name = main.category_name
            order by rand()
            limit    1) category_image
from       wp_rdp_category_images main
group by   category_name
order by   rand()
limit      4
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b971b/5)

If you need all columns in the result set, then use this variant:

```
select     main.*
from       (
            select     category_name,
                       (select   id
                        from     wp_rdp_category_images
                        where    category_name = main.category_name
                        order by rand()
                        limit    1) id
             from       wp_rdp_category_images main
            ) sub
inner join  wp_rdp_category_images main
        on  main.id = sub.id
group by    main.category_name
order by   rand()
limit      4
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b971b/6)

#### PHP Code

Your PHP has an issue so that the first row is repeated. Note that when `$i` is 1 you will execute both the part in the first `if`, but **also** the part in the `else` of the second `if`.

You need to put an `else` before the second `if`:

```php
if ($i == 1) {
    echo '<span><img src="'.$upload_url.$rec->category_image.'" ></span>';  // even
} else if ($i == 2) { // !!!! ADDED "else" here!
    echo '<span><img src="'.$upload_url.$rec->category_image.'" ></span><br>';  // even
}
else {
    echo '<span><img src="'.$upload_url.$rec->category_image.'" ></span>';   // odd
}
```

But your comments seem to suggest that you want to make two columns. In that case it is better to write it like this:

```php
echo '<span><img src="'.$upload_url.$rec->category_image.'" ></span>';  // all
if ($i % 2 == 0) echo '<br>';  // even only
```

Comment: Strange, did you check the fiddle? There are five images, because there are 5 categories. Which category you want to leave out? Also random? I added that to the query & fiddle.

Comment: I need max 4 results. from each cat a random cat_name + random cat_image

Comment: strange. If I do your last update and limit 2 I get 3 as result. When limit = 4 I get 5 as result. Both results are not unique.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? What are you doing differently? There must be something....

Comment: Your update does work correct In phpmyadmin but not in php.

Comment: Then there might be an issue with your PHP code. How do you make the query? And how do you loop?

Comment: I have uploaded at the top of this issue the whole function.

Comment: Please don't use the SQL from my answer in your question. Please put the one you used before, otherwise my answer does not make sense. I am looking at your PHP code now...

Comment: Indeed, you have an error in your PHP code that explains it. See the added paragraph in my answer.

Comment: trincot: i have made a problem in the foreach($record as $key => $rec){ section. That is why I get 1 more then needed. With other words: you select code is working. Sorry for causing this problem.
I added the $i counter to get 2 image on 1 row and 2 at next row. This for presentation purpose. I have to find the good code for this. I have found a solution for it! Thanks.

Comment: I already provided that information in my comments and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like random id

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_name, category_image
FROM `wp_rdp_category_images`
WHERE `id` > RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `wp_rdp_category_images`)   
ORDER BY id
0 LIMIT 4
```

Manually order the 4 results by `category_name` in code.

Comment: Yes, must be order by id. and more